I have a printer and it does not work
I just switched to linux, and i cant use my printer. I did install the driver. I just dont know the command to upload it on my hardware. I tried "sudo ubuntu-drivers install (drivername)" but it does not count the drivername
-Edit: So i basically found a .fmw file for it and downloaded that. But dont know how to install it on my Ubuntu
Ubuntu version:Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Printer: Not sure- My ubuntu says "MF4320-435-UFRII-LT Model HP Designjet T920 PostScript"
Way the printer is connected: USB

Please edit your question and add information a) which Ubuntu release you are using, b) which exact printer model do you have, c) how is the printer connected - USB, LAN network, WLAN, ...?

Did you do a Google search on what an fmw file is? It appears to have noting to do with your printer. For your reference https://fileinfo.com/extension/fmw
